# How to insert records and print them once inserted?

Tags: javascript, php

I have some drop downs where the user makes selections of car make, model, year, mileage and son on, and text boxes where they enter the price of the car, market value, book value and so on and it automatically updates the total market value. When the user clicks the add button to add the car into the database after all the fields have been filled I want to have an alert message which asks the user if they want to print an invoice with all the details. My code so far inserts the records correctly into the database but I don't get the alert message to allow the user to print.

JavaScript

```
$("#add_cars").click(function() {

    var invoice = $("#add_cars_form").serialize();

    $.ajax({

        url: "../includes/add_handlers.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: $("#add_cars_form").serialize(),
        success: function(data){

            if(data === "Data Inserted") {

                if(confirm("Do you want to print invoice?")) {

                   window.location.href="../invoice.php?"+invoice;
                }
            }
            else {
                alert("Error");
            }
        }

    });
});
```

PHP

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['car_make']) && isset($_POST['car_model'])) {

    $message_array = array();

    $make_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['car_make']);
    $model_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['car_model']);

    //echo model_id;

    $make_query = "SELECT make_name FROM car_make WHERE make_id = '$make_id' LIMIT 1";
    $makeResult  = mysqli_query($con, $make_query);
    $makeRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($makeResult);

    $model_query = "SELECT model_name FROM car_model WHERE model_id = '$model_id' LIMIT 1";
    $modelResult  = mysqli_query($con, $model_query);
    $modelRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($modelResult);

    //Handles the user input that is inserted in the database
    $car_year = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['car_year']);
    $cylinder = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['car_cylinder']);
    $liters = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['car_liters']);
    $kilometers = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['car_km']);
    $body_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['car_body_type']);
    $car_option = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['car_option']); 
    $price = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['price']);
    $marketValue= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['marketValue']);
    $TotalValue= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['TotalValue']);

    $insert_query = "INSERT INTO car_attributes
                    (fk_make_id, fk_model_id, year, cylinder, liters, 
                    kilometers, body_type, options, price, marketValue, 
                    TotalValue, buy_now_percenta, auction_percentage, 
                    custom_percentage, total_price_dollar, 
                    total_price_kwanza, custom_total_cost, 
                    total_market_value, buy_now_price, auction_intial_price) 
            VALUES($make_id, $model_id , '$car_year', '$cylinder', 
                    '$liters', '$kilometers', '$body_type', '$car_option', 
                    '$price', '$rateInDollar', '$marketValue', 
                    '$TotalValue')";

    if(mysqli_query($con, $insert_query)) {
        echo "Data Inserted";
    }
    else {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

All help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, this is a DBA forum, not a PHP one. I did notice this `if(data === "Data Inserted")` - three `=` signs in a row - I've never seen that before! However, in future, please keep programming problems for StackOverflow and SQL problems for here - there are some articles on how to ask questions here on my profile - you might want to look? p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: Which part is the problem, PHP or JS? At what point exactly don't things work as expected? Please try to extract and provide a [mcve]. At the very least, you need to provide enough info so anyone here can understand what you are doing and what happens.

Comment: Did you try `data == "Data Inserted"`

Comment: _Silly Question, unrelated to the problem_ Why do you bother getting the `make_name` and `model_name` in 2 queries before the INSERT? Because you do not seem to use that information anywhere

Comment: Did you try a simple debug by adding `console.log(data)` before the IF?

Answer (score 0):

The "success" function doesn't receive a string, but an xhr response object.

Use console.log() to the *data* parameter and search around for the item containing the value you're looking for.

Hint: it's responseText.

You should compare data.responseText with your static value.

Comment: You did notice that the javascript was using jQuery didn't you?

Comment: Ofc. Does that change something? I just tried a $.ajax on google and printed the content of the first parameter of the success function. The responseText contains the html